# Spark-shell: Web UI doesn't change when I execute process

Tags: apache-spark, spark-shell, spark-webui

I use Spark in local mode. I run spark-shell and use a file as a data set. All work very good (for example, I ask spark-shell to count the number of words which begin by "a" in the file and I have the good result), but when I see at the web UI, it doesn't change at all.

Do you have any idea why the web UI doesn't evolve when I run a process?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems, port number will be 8080. Refer doc **https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html**

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I already tried with 8080 and I had the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

When you start the spark-shell in local you are not using Spark Stand Alone. You are running local. You should see a binding to port 404x message. That 404x is what you should use, *if memory serves correct*.

If you type `http://localhost:4040` - or https... or server name or IP-address instead of local host, you will be taken to 4040/jobs and you will see your Jobs, Apps.

If you start using Stand Alone you will see there the App and on port 4040, 4041, etc. whatever is applicable. From Stand Alone you can click to 404x.

Comment: you mean this line : "Spark context Web UI available at http://spark:4040"? It's what is written when I start spark-shell but I can't access to the url...

Comment: u may have 4040 or 4041...try http://localhost:4040